# How to create multiple Files regarding to an object-attribute

Tags: c#, file, streamwriter

A method receives an object list  each entity has the following attributes:

- name
- room

The list contains, for example, the following objects:
name: pc01 room: a1
name: pc02 room: a1
name: pc01 room: XYZ
name: pc02 room: XYZ
name: pc03 room: XYZ

The number of rooms and pc is not known before the program start, as well as the name of the rooms.

I would like to create a file for each room.
Each object should be printed in a line of the object.

For the example above it would mean:

**File 1** 
File-Name =  a1.txt
File-Content:{ 
pc01a1 
pc02a1
}

**File 2** 
File-Name =  XYZ.txt 
File-Content:{ 
pc01XYZ
pc02XYZ
pc03XYZ
}

I know how to loop the object-list and how to write into files, but I don't know, how to create dynamic file names.

I tried the following (results = list of objects):

```
foreach (PC currentPc in results)
{
    //Path to the writer in relation to the attribute room
    var pathFile = "D:\\" + currentPc.room + ".txt";

    StreamWriter writerRoom = new StreamWriter(pathFile);

    //Write Line
    writerRoom.WriteLine(currentPc.room.ToLower() + currentPc.name.ToLower());
    //Close Writer
    writerRoom.Close();
}
```

The code creates the correct files for each room. The problem is, that each file only contains the last object of the list. I would like to have each object of that room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you encounter the same room again, you are overwriting the file you just created. Instead use `AppendAllText`:

```cs
foreach (PC currentPc in results)
{
    // Path to file in relation to the attribute room
    var filePath = $@"D:\{currentPc.room}.txt";
    var textToAppend = $"{currentPc.room.ToLower()}{currentPc.name.ToLower()}\r\n";
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(filePath, textToAppend);
}
```

This method creates the file if it doesn't exist, appends to it and closes it again. `\r\n` is a line break to make it look nice.

**EDIT:**
To empty/delete the files you would need a separate loop to run before the generating one:

```cs
// Delete all files before running generating loop
foreach (PC currentPc in results)
{
    var filePath = $@"D:\{currentPc.room}.txt";
    // Check to see if the file exists
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(filePath); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is almost what I was looking for. Is ist possible to clear the file before writing? If I run the program multiple times, it appends the same text multiple times (for example 2 times pc01).